# Array prints one less number

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to create a program where the user enters n numbers and the computer displays it. But the computer is displaying one less number.

```
int aray[100],elements,n;
printf("Enter no of elements");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("Enter elements");
for(elements=0;elements<n-1;elements++)
{
    scanf("%d%",&aray[elements]);

}
printf("The entered elements are:");
for(elements=0;elements<n-1;elements++)
{
    printf("%d\n",aray[elements]);

}
```

I expect the output to be:

```
Enter no. of elements: 5
Enter elements: 5
4
87
34
56

The entered elements are: 5
4
87
34
56
```

But the output is:

```
Enter elements: 5
4
87
34
56

The entered elements are: 5
4
87
34
```

Comment: `<n-1;` Is wrong. Just `n`.

Comment: You're looping to `n-1`, so you're telling it to stop one early.

Comment: It seems you misunderstand how the last index is calculated. It's true that the last index will be `n - 1`, but because your loop condition is *less than* that is already implied in `elements < n`. You probably have seen something like `elements <= n - 1` and mixed it up with the more common `elements < n`.

Answer (score 2):

You either change **<** to **<=** or change **n-1** to **n**, in your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in the code fragment:

- You should test the return value of `scanf()` to avoid undefined behavior on invalid input.
- You should check that the value `n` input by the user is `<= 100` to avoid accessing elements beyond the end of the array.
- The comparison must be `elements < n` so `elements` takes the values `0`, `1`, ... `n-1`, hence `n` valid index values.
- There is a mistake in the `scanf` format string `"%d%"`.